# Using Mod_Rewrite to remove the GET query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get `page.php?title=foo` to change to `/page/foo`. I've got it working to the point the page.php goes to /page/, but when I do `page.php?title=foo` it rewrites the url to `/page/title?title=foo`.

I'd like to remove the `?title=foo` part of the last url. Any ideas?

I'm new to this - I tried to follow tutorials but am unsure what the `[OR]` and `[NC]` (etc) mean.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^$              [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^title=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^page.php$       page/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule page.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php/?title=$1 // $1 - content of ()
```

So, when user ask `http://example.com/page/foo`, Apache will open him `http://example.com/page.php/?title=foo`. But adressbar is still with `http://example.com/page/foo`

Comment: This produces the same result as the questions; with the exception of being able to handle `page.php` on its own (ie with no parameters)

Comment: Hi; I'm looking for the opposite rewrite ie `/page.php?title=foo` to `/page/foo`

Comment: @Sam You want user type /page.php?title=foo to adressbar?
It's strange for me, sorry.
In my solution user type /page/foo to adressbar and get needed page (/page.php?title=foo)

Comment: Wow; sorry. This is what I wanted. I was going in the other direction. Any idea how to get the browser to continue to display /page.php?title=foo while having the URL in the browser read /page/foo

Answer (score 0):

For all of my devs, I forward all requests to the `index.php`, I exclude all css, js, jp(e)g, pdf, zip etc.

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex  index.php
#ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(ico|docx|php|png|css|jpe?g|js|pdf|txt|mp3)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      index.php
```

**Then in your PHP boot code**,

Setup vars to give content and use `$_GET` later if you want....
Exemple :

```
<?php
function rewrite(){
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
    $params = array("base_url", "locale", "page", "action", "par1", "par2", "par3", "par4");
    $extraParams = preg_match("/\?/i", $link, $extraParamsMatches);
    if($extraParams){
        $link =  explode("?", $link);
        $link = $link[0];
    }
    $link = explode("/", $link);
    $i = 0;
    $vals = array();
    foreach($link as  $key => $value){
        if($params[$key] == "base_url") $value = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        //if(empty($value)) continue ;
        $vals[$params[$key]] = $value;
        if($i == sizeof($params)-1){        
            break;
        }
    $i++;
    }
    return $vals;
}
}    
?>
```

**IMPORTANT**
YOU CAN EDIT THIS CODE TO IMPROVE SECURITY FOR EXAMPLE SANITIZE DATA BEFORE USE IT IN THE FUNCTION ;-)
if the requested page is not found physically or in array from php or database, you can send `header('Location : ',true, 404);` and give your 404 page !!